# My program is setting the first array element to the NUM_EL rather than a random number but the rest of the elements get randoms

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random

```
#define NUM_EL 10

int randomArray1[NUM_EL];
int randomArray2[NUM_EL];
int sumArray[NUM_EL];

//Function Protocol
int IntializeArrayWithPointers(int, int, int);
void DisplayArrayDataWithPointers(int);
int AddTwoArraysWithPointers(int,int,int);

int main()
{   
    *randomArray1=IntializeArrayWithPointers(randomArray1, 0, 1);
    *randomArray2=IntializeArrayWithPointers(randomArray2, 10, 11);
    *sumArray=AddTwoArraysWithPointers(randomArray1,randomArray2,sumArray);
    DisplayArrayDataWithPointers(randomArray1);
    DisplayArrayDataWithPointers(randomArray2);
    DisplayArrayDataWithPointers(sumArray);
}


int IntializeArrayWithPointers(int pointer1[], int a, int b)
{
    int i;
    int* pa;
    pa= pointer1;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_EL; i++)
    {
        pa[i] = rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
    }
}

void DisplayArrayDataWithPointers(int* p)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_EL; i++)
    {
        printf("arrayEL[%d] = %d at %p \n",i,p[i],&p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int AddTwoArraysWithPointers(int a[],int b[],int c[])
{
    int i;
    int *pa;
    int *pb;
    int *pc;

    pa = a;
    pb = b;
    pc = c;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_EL;i++)
{
    *(pc +i)=*(pa +i)+*(pb +i);
}
}
```

The first element, when printing the array, always shows up as the value of `NUM_EL`. That happens even when I set it for `rand`s between 0 and 1. The rest are random like they are supposed to be. The code works perfect except for the 1st element of each array including the sum array.

Comment: That _looks_ correct (though `pa` is completely un-necessary). Are you sure you're printing things out correctly?

Comment: Show the code that calls this function and prints the result, including the declaration of the array you pass in.

Comment: i edited the post to contain the full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the function, you do it like this:

```
*randomArray1=IntializeArrayWithPointers(randomArray1, 0, 1);
```

This will assign the return value of the function to the first element of `randomArray1`. Since you don't want this, you should remove the assignment.

In fact, the function doesn't even return a value so the behavior is undefined. You should declare the function as returning `void`.

Another issue is that the types in your function declarations don't match the types in the function definitions - always make sure they match, and pay attention to compiler warnings which would alert you to this.

Answer (score 0):

*randomArray1=IntializeArrayWithPointers(randomArray1, 0, 1);

This statement sets return value of function to first element of randomArray1.that why it's getting modified.

Remove the assignment and declare IntializeArrayWithPointers() with return type as void.